# error mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement

Tags: python

```
# script de carga 
import csv 
import mysql.connector

# conexao com o banco 
mysql = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='0.0.0.0',
    user='root',
    passwd='mysql',
    database='mydesenv',
    port=3306
)
cur=mysql.cursor()
sql = """insert into mydesenv.tb_load (id, nm_name, dt_load) values (%s, %s, %s)"""
#passo01 - Ler arquivo .csv
csv_data = csv.reader('/Users/eduardoaandrad/Dropbox/Desenv/Script/csv/carga_teste.csv',delimiter=';')
for row in csv_data:
    print(row)
    cur.execute(sql,row)

mysql.commit()
cur.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema está na forma que você está efetuando a leitura do arquivo csv.

---

No seguinte trecho:

```
csv_data = csv.reader('/Users/eduardoaandrad/Dropbox/Desenv/Script/csv/carga_teste.csv',delimiter=';')
```

O arquivo informado está sendo interpretado como uma string, literalmente, com isso o seu loop gera uma saída completamente diferente do esperado na instrução SQL.

Veja esse trecho de leitura do CSV isolado:

```
import csv

csv_data = csv.reader('carga_teste.csv',delimiter=';')

for row in csv_data:
    print(type(row), row)
```

Mesmo que o arquivo não exista, o código será executado exibindo o nome do arquivo no console, gerando uma lista para cada letra:

> Veja online o resultado: https://repl.it/repls/WetShyRadius

---

Para corrigir essa situação, você deve abrir o arquivo com a função `open` e o retorno da função `open` será o parâmetro para o `reader` do `csv`:

```
import csv

with open("carga_teste.csv") as csvFile:
  csv_data = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=';')

  for row in csv_data:
      print(row)
```

> Veja a diferença online: https://repl.it/repls/DeadInnocentOutlier

Efetuei essas correções no código e os dados foram corretamente inseridos.

---

> Documentação: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, muito obrigado pela ajuda !

Corrigir o código com os pontos apontados

```
import mysql.connector
import csv
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', 
                               password='mysql',
                               host='0.0.0.0',
                               database='mydesenv')
cursor = mydb.cursor()
with open('/Users/eduardoaandrad/Dropbox/Desenv/script/csv/carga_teste.csv') as source:
    csv_data = csv.reader(source, delimiter=';')
     for row in csv_data:
        cursor.execute("insert into mydesenv.tb_load (num, nm_name, dt_load) values (%s, %s, %s)",row)
        mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Mas mesmo assim o erro persiste !
notei que o dicionário está retornando tudo como uma única string, exemplo:
['num;nm_name;dt_load']
acredito que deveria retornar dessa forma 
['num';'nm_name';'dt_load']
Obrigado